# Add additional parameter to event callback on parent page

Tags: c#, blazor

I use a component with a bool event callback `OnCollapseChanged`:

```
        <CollapsePanel CollapsedColor="@_collapsedColor"
                   OnCollapseChanged="OnCollapseChanged">
        </CollapsePanel>
```

This event callback calls a function in my C# code:

```cs
private bool _isCollapsed = false;

private Task OnCollapseChanged(bool state)
    {
        _isCollapsed = state;
        return Task.CompletedTask;
    }
```

As I use the CollapsePanel multiple times, I want to add something like an Id, but the component itself does (and should) not know anything about that ID, so what I want to do is something like that:

```
@foreach (var car in _carBaseStates)
{
        <CollapsePanel CollapsedColor="@_collapsedColor"
                   OnCollapseChanged="OnCollapseChanged(car.Id)">
        </CollapsePanel>
}
```

```cs
private HashSet<int> _collapsedIds = new HashSet<int>();

private Task OnCollapseChanged(bool state, int id)
    {
        if(state)
        {
            _collapsedIds.Add(id);
        }
        else
        {
            _collapsedIds.Remove(id);
        }
        return Task.CompletedTask;
    }
```

So basically, I want to add a parameter to the existing one, which is only known on my parent page.

Comment: Wrap the callback in a lambda: `OnCollapseChanged="(state) => OnCollapseChanged(state, car.Id)"`. This proxies the 'state' variable from the original event, and captures the 'car.Id' variable from the loop

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 <CollapsePanel CollapsedColor="@_collapsedColor"
                   OnCollapseChanged="(state)=>OnCollapseChanged(state,car.Id)">
 </CollapsePanel>
```